# Huge amount of instagram request

Tags: php, curl, oauth, instagram

I would like to get my latest insta posts from my own account and show them on my own website. It works great one of my website with a simple file_get_contents().
I have an other insta account and an other site, it has about 100 000< page loads per day, and on this file_get_contets() didnt work so I tried cUrl and I realised that there is a 429 OauthLimitException.

I already browsed the whole internet, read thousands of posts but in every one of them writes only abut the fact not a solution.
What should I do?

Comment: Thanks @JustinT. but the code irrelevant in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cache them. Do not hit the API every time an user load up your site, just cache them somewhere (it could be your server filesystem, so you could drop http and use I/O instead) and fetch your posts from there. As it is, your sites are just  dossing machines.

Comment: yup, cache them and update them a couple of times per day (like a once every hour daemon?)

Comment: Thanks @AndreaGolin, you're absolutely right. I will do this.